# tkinter.messagebox.showinfo doesn't always work

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have just started working with Python's `tkinter` GUI tool. In my code I create an simple GUI with one button and I want to show the user a `messagebox` if they click on the button.

Currently, I use the `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo` method for it. I code on a Windows 7 computer using IDLE. If I run the code from IDLE everything works fine, but if I try to run it standalone in the Python 3 interpreter it doesn't work any more. Instead it logs this error to the console:

```
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'
```

Do you have any tips for me? My code is:

```
import tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.temp = False
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry()
        self.geometry("500x250")
        self.bt = tkinter.Button(self,text="Bla",command=self.click)
        self.bt.place(x=5,y=5)
    def click(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("blab","bla")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you provide the *full error traceback*, formatted as code?

Comment: Try to import the module `messagebox` and then replace `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("blab","bla")` with `messagebox.showinfo("blab","bla")` to see if something changes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`messagebox`, along with some other modules like `filedialog`, does not automatically get imported when you `import tkinter`. Import it explicitly, using `as` and/or `from` as desired.

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'
>>> import tkinter.messagebox
>>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')
'ok'
>>> from tkinter import messagebox
>>> messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')
'ok'
```

Comment: Thats it (the from tkinter import messagebox) thanks for the solution, I dont know wy it works by using the IDLE but with this solution it works.

Comment: have an solution wy it works in the IDLE, its written with tkinter.

Answer (score -8):

This is case sensitive - `tkinter` should be `Tkinter` wherever it is used. I did this and was able to run your example.

Comment: The OP is using 3.x (note the question tags), where `Tkinter` is renamed to `tkinter` (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes). You are presumably using 2.x.